# pushstate/pop state issue on IOS - history api/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-history

I am having a weird issue only on iphone and ipad. I have built the following functionality:

On an ecommerce site, when the user clicks on the browser's back button once on the checkout success page, i redirect him to the homepage. This works great on all major browsers.

However, on IOS, before hitting the back button, the page is automatically redirected to the homepage (on the checkout success page)

I have the following codes:

```
(function() {

var SuccessPage ={

    extractDomain:function(url){
        var domain;
        if (url.indexOf("://") > -1) {
            domain = url.split('/')[2];
        }
        else {
            domain = url.split('/')[0];
        }
        domain = domain.split(':')[0];

        return domain;
    }

}


if(window.location.href.indexOf("checkout/onepage/success") > -1) {
    history.pushState(null, null, window.location.href);
    window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
        window.location.assign("http://"+SuccessPage.extractDomain(window.location.href))
    });
}

})();
```

I have tried using set timeout on the pop state event.. but makes no cigar :(
And i cannot figure out why IOS is not understanding this code..

Please help

Comment: i just came accross history.js, is this worth implementing, or is it too overkill, for the simple task i am trying to do?

Comment: according to my findings, safari would fire a popstate event on page load..

Answer (score 3):

got it working:

```
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("checkout/onepage/success") > -1) {
    if(window.history && history.pushState && history.state !== undefined){
        history.pushState(null, null, window.location.href);
        window.addEventListener("popstate", function(event) {
            if(navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/)){
                if(!page_loaded){
                    page_loaded = true;
                    return false;
                }else{
                    window.location.assign("http://"+SuccessPage.extractDomain(window.location.href))
                }
            }else{
                window.location.assign("http://"+SuccessPage.extractDomain(window.location.href))
            }

        },false);
    }
}
```